# having 2 columns between x and y value mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.SCHEDULE_START, T1.SCHEDULE_END, T2.SCHEDULE_TYPE_ID, T2.SCHEDULENAME
FROM schedule_intermediate T1 JOIN schedule_type T2 ON T1.SCHEDULE_TYPE_ID = T2.SCHEDULE_TYPE_ID
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reservation R JOIN schedule_intermediate SI ON R.SCHEDULEID_GENERATED = SI.SCHEDULEID_GENERATED
    WHERE RESOURCEID = 456 
    AND SI.SCHEDULEID_GENERATED = 4 
    AND R.RESERVATIONDUEDATE = '2014-08-06 07:50:00'
    AND R.RESERVATIONEXPIREDATE = '2014-08-06 08:35:00'
    HAVING T1.SCHEDULE_START != DATE_FORMAT('2014-08-06 07:50:00', '%H:%i:%s')
    AND    T1.SCHEDULE_END != DATE_FORMAT('2014-08-06 08:35:00', '%H:%i:%s')
) = 0
ORDER BY T1.SCHEDULE_START
```

Which is used to select **ONLY** the schedules where there would be no collisions with other schedules.

This produces:

[image]

However it excludes `7:50:00` and `08:35:00` from the schedules and the period from `08:35:00 to 09:20:00` is excluded.

I want to exclude periods of time **between** the ranges provided, however, I need to **include** the specific time provided (`07:50:00 and 08:35:00`), just **excluding** the minutes within that range (from `7:51:00 - 8:34:00`).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

I already tried:

```
HAVING T1.SCHEDULE_START <= DATE_FORMAT('2014-08-06 07:50:00', '%H:%i:%s')
AND    T1.SCHEDULE_END >= DATE_FORMAT('2014-08-06 08:35:00', '%H:%i:%s')
```

But this one returns 0 columns, likewise inverting the signs produces the same result. I can't figure any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to exclude all results that either start or end in the specified time? it is not clear from your question. if it is, then the relevant section could be...

```
AND ( 
      T1.SCHEDULE_START <= DATE_FORMAT('2014-08-06 07:50:00', '%H:%i:%s')
      OR T1.SCHEDULE_START >= DATE_FORMAT('2014-08-06 08:35:00', '%H:%i:%s')
   ) 
AND ( 
      T1.SCHEDULE_END <= DATE_FORMAT('2014-08-06 07:50:00', '%H:%i:%s') 
      OR T1.SCHEDULE_END >= DATE_FORMAT('2014-08-06 08:35:00', '%H:%i:%s')
    )
```

Comment: I want to exclude periods of time that are within the ranges specified. That means anything that starts within 07:50:00 and 08:35:00 shouldn't be shown. However if the period starts or ends on the limits (7:50:00 or 8:35:00), they should be shown.